# jQueryUI accordion causes wrapping when using the icon

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion

Using the baic redmond theme from jQueryUI, my accordians are not sitting right. I thought something in my stylesheet was causing issues, but I removed it and it is still funky. I stripped it way, way back to this and it's still wrapping the triangle icon and text on 2 x lines.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Nodes</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/DFCx/css/jQueryUI_redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/DFCx/js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/DFCx/js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/DFCx/js/page/Nodes/view.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="accordion" class="accordion">
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <div>junk</div>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <div>junk</div>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <div>junk</div>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <div>junk</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The accordion script (view.js) just has:

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({ 
    autoHeight: false, 
    collapsible: true, 
    header: 'h3' 
});
```

The accordion works perfectly, opens, closes, fits and so forth, it just wraps the h3 when it puts the icon in place!

see https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeZv5.png for a screenshot sample of the result

When I use "icons: false" in the accordion config it leaves the icons off and works as expected, but I'd like to have them there! Tried different UI stylesheets (overcast etc.) and all the same problem in different colours.

Is there something I'm missing?

-- update (not sure if it's a solution yet tho)
In  the jQueryUI css file was this line:

```
.ui-icon { display: block; text-indent: -99999px; overflow: hidden; background-repeat: no-repeat; }
```

which I edited to be

```
.ui-icon { display: block; float: left; text-indent: -99999px; overflow: hidden; background-repeat: no-repeat; }
```

(note added float:left;)

This has fixed the icon positioning in the headings, and works a treat. Fingers crossed that it doesn't have any nasty flow-on affects for other icons :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be that the generated CSS you're using does not include styles for accordions.

Try to use a different CSS, for example, this one: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/themes/base/jquery-ui.css.

Or, choose the theme you are using from this page: http://blog.jqueryui.com/2010/09/jquery-ui-1-8-5/.

You still need to ensure you style the accordion headers [as documented](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/) (and suggested by Larry):

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3><a href="#">First header</a></h3>
    <div>First content</div>
    <h3><a href="#">Second header</a></h3>
    <div>Second content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your titles should be wrapped in an `<a>` tag as well:

```
<h3><a href="#">Title</a></h3>
```

Comment: sadly, it made no difference. :(

Comment: @CrazyChris, what Larry suggested fixed the problem you posted: http://jsfiddle.net/william/urDcR/. If this doesn't fix the problem in your program, you may want to check if you override any CSS for the icon.

Comment: @William - I have tried with and without the links in the headings, same result. Also, the only css I have loaded is the one I downloaded from jQueryUI, hence my confusion.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue, and I used this to correct it:

```
/* correct accordion headers*/
.ui-accordion-header span{ position: absolute; }
.ui-accordion-header a { margin-left: 20px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is the combined solution by @ton and @LarryLustig.

1. Your titles should be wrapped in an `<a>`

   `<h3><a href="#">Title</a></h3>`
2. Style in page

   `.ui-accordion-header span{ position: absolute; }
   .ui-accordion-header a { margin-left: 20px; }`